# Proving this is a metric

Tags: general-topology

Let (X, d) be a metric space. Let Y be a subset of X. Consider
the function dY : Y × Y → R given by dY (y1, y2) = d(y1, y2).

Show dY is a metric on Y .

Show that the metric topology induced by dY is the same as the subspace topology
Y inherits from X with its metric topology.

I am even a little confused about what exactly this metric is doing. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: This metric is the exact same as the metric $d$, only restricted to $Y$

Comment: So it is just a metric because d is a metric for X?

Comment: Also, I am a little confused how two points in YxY can be compared to points in X

Comment: Elements in YxY are to be compared with elements in XxX, ( not X ). And Y is a subset of X

Comment: Thank you. I get this part now